# Debug failing Gatsby build on Netlify (Can't resolve component)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby, netlify

Site runs fine in Development. Site Github repo is connected to Netlify. When pushing changes the build is failing with Netlify.

It looks as if some of my components aren't resolving properly in the build phase. But resolve fine in development.

Trimmed down logs below, starting at where things start to fail:

```
1:30:26 PM: failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 24.846s
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/SEO' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/SEO' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/SEO' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/SEO' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/SEO' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/SEO' in '/opt/build/repo/src/templates'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/layout'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages'
1:30:26 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
1:30:26 PM: Can't resolve '../components/Section' in '/opt/build/repo/src/templates'
1:30:26 PM: not finished run queries - 24.930s
1:30:26 PM: not finished Generating image thumbnails - 24.909s
1:30:26 PM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
1:30:26 PM: Caching artifacts
1:30:26 PM: Started saving node modules
1:30:26 PM: Finished saving node modules
1:30:26 PM: Started saving pip cache
1:30:26 PM: Finished saving pip cache
1:30:26 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Started saving go dependencies
1:30:27 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
1:30:29 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
1:30:30 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
1:30:29 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
1:30:30 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m56.320874616s
```

[Full log here](https://pastebin.com/ZQ0wTp9c)

Comment: When you say it runs fine in development, are you referring to `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` and then `gatsby server`. Also, are you positive that those components are actually pushed to your remote repo?

Comment: @ZekeHernandez You prompted me to check the Github repo. The files exist however the file name for "Section" and "SEO" was lower case in the repo but not locally and wasn't being updated with new pushes. Manually changed the file name in the repo and it's fixed the problem. Thank you. Post an answer so I can give you points.

Comment: Thanks, I love me some points haha.

And yeah, I've lost a good minute to case-sensitive Git mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend checking your remote repository to see if the files you have locally have actually been pushed there.

Comment: And that they are in the right case! (In my situation, I had replaced files in the same location with similar files with different casing in the names.)